# Php - PRO and CON for streaming VS. writing /caching

Tags: php, caching, streaming, download, filestream

I have this dilemma many times - and I would like one time and for all adjust the answer in my head .

While creating files with PHP , like *.zip , *pdf or any other , PHP will give you two operational options :

- write to disk.
- stream with headers to direct download.

things to consider are :

- Security (the usual)
- CPU and serving time for file
- file integrity
- file updates
- any other consideration that I did not list .

A practical example :

Let´s say that I have a website to download a packed zip with images .

If I stream the zip - it will obviously cost CPU (and time ).

If I write to disk - it can be security problem (assuming someone can "crawl" the site , find the zip folder or files somehow, and bulk download all)

If I write to disk , I will also need to check somehow if the files inside the zip should be updated or not , Plus I will have to verify the file´s integrity .

Anyhow - I would like to hear what people has to say about which one is the preferred method under which circumstances , what are best practices for this , or any other insight .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is of no concern *if you do it right*. Just don't store the files inside the public webroot, or otherwise configure your web server to not serve these files directly.

With that out of the way, it depends on what you want. If you need to serve the same zip again and again, of course it makes sense to zip it once and write it to disk, from where you will serve it the next time. That's a simple *caching* strategy.
If you need to make sure you have the latest version of the zip, make a hash of the contents in some fashion. For example:

1. list of files to zip `(foo.txt, bar.jpg, baz.doc)`
2. make hash `$hash = md5(foo.txt, bar.jpg, baz.doc)`
3. if `$hash.zip` doesn't already exist, create it
4. serve `$hash.zip`

That's a typical caching strategy to avoid doing costly operations again and again.

Comment: you see - I already learn something - I was stupid enough to use internal CRC - which requires to open the file each time costing CPU . using a hash to append to filename makes it more economic I guess. Can you elaborate a bit more on the "do it right" part regarding security - what consideration should I have ?

Comment: Simply do not make the file publicly accessible. Just because you're writing it to disk does not mean anybody can download it. That's only the case if you write it to disk *inside the publicly accessible webroot*. You can simply write it to disk outside the webroot, problem solved.

Comment: This is true under the condition that everyone with the right access can freely download ALL files. but what if I need to restrict download on a file-to-file basis ? simply serving the ONE link on permission would not resolve this problem (unless I am missing something)

Comment: There are many solutions for authorized file downloads. Please search for it. Option 1: Use PHP for authorization and `readfile()` to serve the file. Option 2: Apache's mod_xsendfile.

Answer (score 1):

If the same identical zip file is going to be downloaded multiple times, it makes sense to cache it (on disk or some other persistent storage). If you include a hash of the zip's contents as part of the file name (or whatever identifier you cache the data under), then it's trivial to see if your cached value matches what you want to serve.

If any given zip file is going to be downloaded only once, then it makes more sense to just stream it directly.

Comment: Ok - but what if the file is the same for example, but it needs only a different name (like append user name or date) -would that be considered a "one-time-download" ?  and what about security while caching ?